# Sysinternals Process Monitor (ProcMon): Working with Time of Day Filter

Tags: sysinternals, procmon, process-monitor

I am using [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to debug some incoming events.
Now I am trying to create a filter on 'Time Of Day' in order to filter those incoming events which time is greater than an specific time.

For example, If I want to obtain those incoming events which time is greater than '13:30' how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date&Time`, `more than` and give a date and time. Since it is `10.10.2020` on my machine, it seems that time is localized (Germany here).

[image: Time filter in Process Monitor]

Answer (score 1):

Timeofday is measured in seconds. To filter events later than 13:30, say, set it to greater than 48600 (`13*3600 + 30*60`).